# Newsletter disabled, but still appears on website during checkout

Tags: checkout

I disabled the mage_newsletter in Magento, but newsletter subscription still appears in checkout when a customer buys an item.

I have tried flushing the cache, but this makes no difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware (anyone, correct me if I am wrong, since new features do appear in new versions of magento), placing subscribe at checkout is not a core magento feature.

3rd party extension, such as mailchimp (for one), can do this, so I would check for any newsletter 3rd party extensions as the reason for this.

This can also be a feature of any 3rd party checkouts (like a one step checkout)

Comment: You are correct. This issue was resolved by disabling the subscription in the Magemonkey MailChimp extension. Cheers.